# Skip Error rows and report all error creating rows in Select convert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a SSIS package which runs a Stored procedure (SP). The SP uses Insert INTO.

I am using lot of conversions in the select statement i.e. when a conversion throws an error and nothing is inserted.

**1. I want to My insert to be successful for all successful conversions in select.**

so my select statement should return me all successful conversions:

**SELECT 

into #tmp
convert(a..) if error skip row,

convert(b..) if error skip row**

....report all the skipped rows as in insert them to a different table

and then I can simply do

insert into....
select * from #tmp

Answer (score 0):

A case statement in the select might work for you.

If you have

```
Select
   CASE
     WHEN ISNUMERIC(Column1) = 1 THEN Column1
     ELSE NULL
   END,
   CASE
     WHEN ISDATE(Column2) = 1 THEN Column2
   END
FROM Table1
```

The ELSE is left off of the second statement to show that it's optional but a good idea for clarity.

IF the case evaluates to true the row for that column is inserted. If it evaluates to false, it returns NULL and nothing is inserted and you don't get an error.

Using the where clause has the disadvantage of eliminating entire rows if a single column has invalid data in it.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I want to skip the whole row for any bad data. As more I read about it, it appears to me that its best to handle the data Purity at source, than loading data in SQL and doing it esp when i have 33 million rows coming in daily.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the type first and see if they work.  Say you're converting a string to an integer, and a second string to a date.

For example:

DECLARE @ExampleTable TABLE (FirstString varchar(20), SecondString varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @ExampleTable SELECT '1', '1/2/1990'

INSERT INTO @ExampleTable SELECT 'A', '1/2/1990'

INSERT INTO @ExampleTable SELECT '1', 'B'

THEN:

Insert into #tmp

SELECT * FROM @ExampleTable WHERE ISNUMERIC(FirstString) = 1 AND ISDATE(SecondString) = 1

Would give you all the rows where a conversion would succeed

Comment: is there a faster way to do it? I have 20 columns and millions of rows, so my guess is, applying check condition on every column in where would gonna kill it.

Comment: Hi batman.  Is this a once-off or something that you do regularly?  If it's a table to that you regularly update, you could add a columns "IsNotClean" and mark it as such (and index on it) so that you could just skip it the next time, or you could check on a record-by-record basis as the data goes into the table (if it's added line by line).  I just ran this on a derived table on 6.5 million records (but just one column) and it ran in under two minutes.  I think if it's a once-off you should be okay, but if you need to run it regularly it might not be perfect.

Comment: Hi Bab, When i did it for my 33 million rows my server threw a out of Memory exception and my data will grow with time. I have 33 million rows coming in daily as of now. So i guess handling data purity at source would be the best option. Also, now i am thinking of upgrading to 2012 might help too as it has lot more functions to deal with such issues. anything you would like to add?